# How to run commands at login on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, login, xmodmap

I have the file ~/.xmodmap where i swap a few keys on my keyboard. This file was loaded properly on my previous Ubuntu desktop but since the upgrade to 12.04 it's no longer loaded when I login to my desktop.

What's the proper way to execute commands when we login to the desktop in ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Try putting the xmodmap command in with the rest of your startup apps.

Answer (score 6):

search for "startup applications" in your dash.
-Click on add
-Name it and enter the command you want to execute
-Click ok and restart to verify

Answer (score 2):

Use "greeter-setup-script" and "session-setup-script" with Lightdm in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.

The greeter-setup-script option runs the script (as root) before login.

```
greeter-setup-script = (Script to run when starting a greeter)
```

The session-setup script runs the script (as root) after login.

```
session-setup-script = (Script to run when starting a user session)
```

Comment: This answer is my favorite, but doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu Mate... saaad  :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to execute user specific commands during boot up time.
The commands or scripts that we want to execute should be added to the script /etc/rc.local

The script /etc/rc.local will be similar to a shell script. Make sure it's exit status is 0 to avoid startup errors.

This /etc/rc.local script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.

-Ram

Comment: This answer is incorrect. rc.local is a shell script, and is executed outside of the X environment, and indeed as root, so it won't work for this requirement.

Comment: @RobinGreen, In that case, what is the correct answer then?

Comment: I guess either of the other answers on this page?