# Run commands at startup

Tags: live-cd, command-line, customization

My problem is as follows:
I want to to modify my Ubuntu LiveCD to run several commands at startup, but I'm new to Ubuntu development and don't know how to do this. What is the proper way to run these commands every time I boot Ubuntu?

Here are ex. commands:

```
sudo rm /home/ubuntu/Desktop/examples.desktop
sudo perl -e 'print("[DesktopEntry]\nVersion=1.0\nType=Application\nTerminal=false\nIcon=xinput_calibrator\nName=Calibraion\nExec=env /usr/bin/xinput_calibrator\n");' > /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Calibrate.desktop
sudo /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Calibrate.desktop
```

**EDIT!!!**

I've actually tried modifying rc.local file and it looks like this now:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

sudo rm /home/ubuntu/Desktop/examples.desktop
sudo perl -e 'print("[DesktopEntry]\nVersion=1.0\nType=Application\nTerminal=false\nIcon=xinput_calibrator\nName=Calibraion\nExec=env /usr/bin/xinput_calibrator\n");' > /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Calibrate.desktop
sudo /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Calibrate.desktop

exit 0
```

But still I don't know if it is going to work. I want to be sure before I'll build iso.

**EDIT 2!!!**

I've build iso file using this tutorial:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization
I've done steps:

1. Extract the CD .iso contents
2. Extract the Desktop system
3. then I've edited the rc.local file and saved
4. Assembling the file system ( I've ommited "Regenerate manifest" point)

and now I get error

> No init found. Try passing init= bootarg

while booting my LiveCD.

passing init= bootarg results in:

> /bin/sh: bootarg: not found

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: you don't need sudo in `rc.local`. remove them other wise it won't work

Comment: I've edited the question again

Comment: Would it be easier to create a live usb with persistence, so you can store your settings, and then boot off of that?

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not possible. The build must be read only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To execute a script at startup of Ubuntu

```
Edit /etc/rc.local and add your commands
The script must always end with exit 0
```

To execute a script upon rebooting Ubuntu

```
Put your script in /etc/rc0.d
Make it executable (sudo chmod +x myscript)
Note: The scripts in this directory are executed in alphabetical order
```

The name of your script must begin with K99 to run at the right time.

I'm not sure if this will help you in your situation but I will look some more and see what I can come up with.

To execute a script at shutdown

```
Put your script in /etc/rc6.d
Make it executable (sudo chmod +x myscript)
Note: The scripts in this directory are executed in alphabetical order
```

The name of your script must begin with K99 to run at the right time.

This question has been asked before here is the link.
[How to run commands at login on ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123055/how-to-run-commands-at-login-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: **Bingo**that is the right way to do it. Build your ISO and it should function. Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: EDITED QUESTION AGAIN

Answer (score 0):

It is a botched build. In other words it is faulty you need to use another disc. If you decide to use a different disc make sure you use a different type to omit other problems. You need to make sure that you do this so we can continue troubleshooting. That is the first step. Botched builds are quite frequent and should always be a first step towards troubleshooting when trying to do something like this. If you attempt this and you still get the same error get back to me I have a friend who does this kind of thing on the regular and I am going to pass this on to him and see what he thinks. But in the meantime get busy.

Very Respectfully,

Matthew Kaulfers