# How do I autorun terminal commands at startup in Lubuntu 14.04 LiveCD?

Tags: command-line, bash, lubuntu, live-cd, autorun

I'm doing some remastering of Lubuntu 14.04 LiveCD, and need to run the following command at startup:

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 10.10.10.1 netmask 255.255.0.0
```

First, I tried modifying **rc.local** as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local

/sbin/ifconfig eth0 10.10.10.1 netmask 255.255.0.0

exit 0
```

Execution bit was set via:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

That didn't work, so I tried writing this bash script (which I set to executable) and placing it in **/usr/bin/**

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 10.10.10.1 netmask 255.255.0.0
```

In conjunction with the above action, I modified **rc.local** thus:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local

/usr/bin/myscript

exit 0
```

Didn't work. Keeping the bash script in **/usr/bin/**, I edited **/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart** with this line:

```
@/usr/bin/myscript
```

This, too, failed to produce the desired result. Have I made a mistake with something I've tried, or is there something else I should be doing?

**EDIT:**

I've been unable to figure out how to utilize the casper parameters mentioned in Elder Greek's answer. Any further help on that front would be greatly appreciated.

The comments in the link he/she posted turned out to be helpful, though. One commenter pointed out that the bash script located at **/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper-bottom/23networking** can be edited to assign a static ip to eth0.

The commenter also mentions editing the **/etc/network/interfaces** file, which is what I did. It works, but at a price: a lengthy delay at bootup while waiting on the network to configure. Here are the relevant bits:

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

**~/isolinux/isolinux.cfg**

```
default live
label live
    say Booting an Ubuntu Live session...
    kernel /casper/vmlinuz
    append file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash ip=frommedia --
```

In my experience, what normally happens is that, regardless of what changes you make to the **network/interfaces** file, when the LiveCD boots, it's forced to a default state by the **23networking** bash script I mentioned prior. The **ip=frommedia** edit at the end of **isolinux.cfg** forces the script to use whatever is present in the network/interfaces file.

As the commenter mentioned, the **23networking** script can be edited to set a static ip. If anyone can help me with that (not so good with bash scripting), that would be great.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. I believe thi8s question has been asked and answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/166986/run-commands-at-startup?rq=1

Comment: I've seen that question/answer. But as my post specifies, that solution is not working. The portions of the answer pertaining to running a script on reboot or shutdown don't seem relevant to my application. It's entirely possible that I've made a mistake somewhere, and if that's the case, I'd appreciate someone pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I attempt to run `/sbin/ifconfig eth0 10.10.10.1 netmask 255.255.0.0` manually I get
`SIOCSIFADDR: Operation not permitted`

`SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted`

`SIOCSIFNETMASK: Operation not permitted`

Following the logic of that, I attempted

`sudo /sbin/ifconfig eth0 10.10.10.1 netmask 255.255.0.0`

Which completed without error. It would seem that you need super user powers for this to succeed.

You may find this documentation useful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Further research on the link above indicates that there is a casper parameter which is in the form:

ip=IFACE,ADDRESS,NETMASK,GATEWAY[:IFACE,ADDRESS,NETMASK,GATEWAY]*

I found this by googling **Ubuntu Live CD custom static ip**