# Proper way to execute a script on system startup?

Tags: system

As of Ubuntu 12.04, what is the proper/clean way to make the system execute a script upon boot? (not upon user login) e.g. running a daemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is a way to execute user specific commands during boot up time. The commands or scripts that we want to execute should be added to the script `/etc/rc.local`

The script `/etc/rc.local` will be similar to a shell script. Make sure it's exit status is 0, add the following line to that script "exit 0".

This `/etc/rc.local` script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123055/how-to-run-commands-at-login-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Also you can see examples in `/etc/init.d/`

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#what-is-upstart) which I find to be useful.