# Wallpaper settings via nitrogren are lost after rebooting?

Tags: 12.10, unity, multiple-monitors, reboot, desktop-background

I use `nitrogen` to set a different wallpaper for each monitor.  It requires disabling of the Nautilus desktop, but works great.  Until I reboot...at which point the settings are lost and I go back to the default Gnome wallpaper which is the same on both monitors.

Anyway to make the nitrogen settings stick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You add nitrogen to your commands to run at log in

```
nitrogen --restore
```

[How to run commands at login on ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123055/how-to-run-commands-at-login-on-ubuntu-12-04)